# passing values of a radio button from erb to post method in sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, radio-button, sinatra, erb

I just started with web programming and have chosen Sinatra for the same. I am stuck at passing a value of radio button from erb to a post method. However I could do the same for a text input field but unable to achieve the same for a radio button.

The radio buttons in erb are from an array created using an instance variable from a get method. Please help with what I am missing.

Here are my snippets.

program.rb

```
get '/stop' do
@output = []
IO.popen("lxc-ls --active").each do |line|
  @output << line
end
erb :stop
end

post '/stop' do
@s = params[:tostop]
p @s + "HI"
#IO.popen("lxc-stop -n '#{params[:stop]}'")
end
```

stop.erb

```
<form action="/stop" method="post">
<% @output.each do |button| %>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="tostop" value="<%= button %>"><%= button %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
<input type="submit" name="stop" value="Stop!">
</form>
```

[UPDATE]

Somehow I could pass the radio button's value and could see the value by doing the following.

program.rb

```
post '/stop' do
"You Selected #{params[:tostop]}"
 IO.popen("lxc-stop -n '#{params[:stop]}'")
end
```

But, the same is not passed to IO.popen("lxc-stop -n '#{params[:stop]}'").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it looks like it might just be a typo. I think you're passing `params[:stop]` to the `lxc-stop -n` command, when you probably mean `params[:tostop]`.

You might also consider sanitizing the input a bit since you're passing a value that someone could forge directly to your OS... Maybe make sure the `params[:tostop]` is in the list output by `lxc-ls --active`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. The typo is in the question but not in the actual program. But it is wired that the whole thing started working when I replaced IO.popen with %x<lxc-stop -n #{params[:tostop]}>. I had to completely remove quotes for the instance variable. But I am still confused why this dint work with IO.popen. Also can you please elaborate "sanitizing the input"?. The whole idea is to make a small web interface where each of my colleagues can create, start and stop 5 containers of their own. How can I make this quotas work? I am a systems engineer and very new to web world. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah, OK. Well I guess I would ask why you're using IO.popen if you aren't using the IO object it returns and you're not using a block (which is usually why one would use IO.popen to run a system command). You might just try a simpler approach, like `system("lxc-stop -n '#{params[:tostop]}'")`. Or you could wrap the command in backticks if you need to capture the output.

Comment: Also, as far as sanitizing the input goes, there are numerous options, but as I mentioned in the answer, I think the simplest way is to check if ``lxc-ls --active`.split("\n").include? params[:tostop]` which makes sure the param passed is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Btw, Can you please give some direction on restricting the user with 5 containers and also restricting his operations on those 5 which he creates?

Comment: Got to admit, I think that qualifies as a new question as that is a pretty broad "aside". You're talking about introducing some form of persistence, authentication, possibly authorization... Not something simple to describe in a comment.